# Pelican - How to include different secitons in one long static page?

Tags: pelican

I want to create a long static website with Pelican and I'm not sure how to do it. I've got 3 sections with corresponding content in md files:

- landing.md
- about.md
- contact.md

Each of this section has separate template defined:

- landing.html
- about.html
- contact.html

I define it in the markdown file with `Template: <file>`. I would like to simply generate one site that will have all these 3 sections/pages one under another. I tried something like this:

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p>index.html</p>
{% for article in articles_page.object_list %}
    {% block article %}{% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
<p>end of index.html</p>
{% endblock %}
```

and in templates:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block head %}
  {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block article %}
<h1 style="color: red">{{article.title}}</h1>
{{article.content}}
{% endblock %}
```

but I am not allowed to add `block article` in the template, it results in `articles_page undefined` error.

Is it at all possible to generate the file like that in Pelican? What would be the best practice to do it? I would like to have a one long static website and be able to maintain the content conveniently, hence I thought about SSG.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the content for the pages in a content/pages directory then you can loop through in `index.html` them using

```
{% for p in pages %}
    <h1>{{ p.title }}</h1>
    {{ p.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

The `pages` variable is [available on all templates](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/themes.html#common-variables).

You may want to have the pages in a certain order and so you can either add an attribute, such as "order" to the meta data and then sort by that with

```markdown
---
Title: Contact
Order: 1
---
# Contact
```

```
{% for p in pages|sort(attribute="order") %}
    <h1>{{ p.title }}</h1>
    {{ p.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or another way is to have multiple loops and filter the loop using [selectattr](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr), such as

```
{% for p in pages|selectattr("title", "eq", "Contact") %}
    <h1>{{ p.title }}</h1>
    {{ p.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

You could add one of these loops to a partial template for each section and include it into your `index.html` with

```
{% include "landing.html" %}
{% include "about.html" %}
{% include "contact.html" %}
```